# Servidor iis express en un servicio c#

Tags: c#, iis-express

Hola estoy tratando de cargar una pagina web como servicio, un iis exprees de servicio, al intentar correr un servicio con el proceso de iiexpress me da error el servicio al correrlo, no levanta siquiera el log, podria alguien ayudarme? codigo a continuacion:

```
 public partial class iiscustom : ServiceBase
{
    public iiscustom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Process _iisProcess;
    private StreamWriter _logWriter;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", $"/c {Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86), "IIS Express"), "iisexpress.exe")} \"/config:\"{Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "applicationHost.config")} /systray:false /trace:error")
        { CreateNoWindow = true, WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, RedirectStandardInput = true, UseShellExecute = false };
        

        Process _iisProcess = new Process();
        _iisProcess.StartInfo = psi;
        _iisProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        // Registrar un evento para manejar la salida estándar del proceso
        _iisProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data); // Imprimir la salida del proceso
                                       // Aquí puedes escribir la salida del proceso en un archivo de registro
        };
        _iisProcess.Start();
        _iisProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();            
    }       


    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (_iisProcess == null || _iisProcess.HasExited) return;
        _iisProcess.Kill();
        _iisProcess.Dispose();
    }
}
```

estoy intentando iniciar con cmd el proceso iiexpress.exe, desde una aplicacion de consola me funciona pero aca no
tambien intente con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
public partial class iiscustom : ServiceBase
{
    public iiscustom()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Process _iisProcess;
    private StreamWriter _logWriter;
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86),
                "IIS Express"),"iisexpress.exe"),
            Arguments = "/config:" + Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "applicationHost.config") +
                        " /systray:false /trace:error",
            WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        };
        _iisProcess = new Process {StartInfo = startInfo};
        _logWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\Servidor.log", true);
        _iisProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => _logWriter.WriteLine(e.Data);
        _iisProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => _logWriter.WriteLine(e.Data);
        _iisProcess.Start();
        _iisProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        _iisProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (_iisProcess == null || _iisProcess.HasExited) return;
        _iisProcess.Kill();
        _iisProcess.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Alguien sabe como puedo lograr ejecutar un dbug, o de que forma se puede hacer funcionar, o existe alguna alternativa? no quiero ejecutar el iis, de windows sino el iis express, bueno gracias